# AnyDice error: Boolean values can only be numbers

Tags: anydice

I'm trying to write code that helps calculate the probability of success.
Negative luck adds cursed dice to the bonus dice pool, which in the case of a crit burns additional dice from the skill level.
If the bones are completely burned and there is still one -1, then the skill check failed.
Anydice issues:

**calculation error

Boolean values can only be numbers, but you provided "d{?}".
Depending on what you want, you might need to create a function.**

complaining about logic checks

```
CHARACTERISTIC_BONUS: 2
SKILL_LEVEL: 4
LUCK_LEVEL: 1
CORRUPTED_LEVEL: -1
SKILL_DICE: d{0,0,0,1}
CORRUPTED_DICE: d{-1,0,0,-1}
ROLL_LEVEL: 6


function: sand {
 if CORRUPTED_LEVEL< 0 
 {
  ADDITIONAL_DICE_POOL: SKILL_LEVELdSKILL_DICE + LUCK_LEVELdCORRUPTED_DICE
 }
 else 
 {
  ADDITIONAL_DICE_POOL: SKILL_LEVELdSKILL_DICE
 }
 result: ADDITIONAL_DICE_POOL
}


function: additionalcheck 
{
 if [sand] < 0{
  result: 1
 }
 else{
  result: 0
 }
}

function: skillcheck {
 RL_TEMP: 0
if [additionalcheck] < 0 {
 RL_TEMP: 0
}
else{
  RL_TEMP: 0
  ROLL_RESULT: 1d12 + CHARACTERISTIC_BONUS
  if ROLL_RESULT > ROLL_LEVEL {
   
   RL_TEMP: 1
  }
}
 result: RL_TEMP
}

output [skillcheck]
```

There are unnecessary elements in the code, but I will be able to fix them only when I understand the principle of anydice

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error message means what it says — you can't do something like:

```
if d2 = 1 { \ do something \ } else { \ do something else \ }
```

because AnyDice would have to somehow execute *both* paths, since `d2` can be either 1 or 2, and combine the resulting arbitrary program states into some kind of weird "quantum superposition".  AnyDice is pretty clever, but it's not *that* clever.

In your program, `[sand]` returns a die.  When you do `if [sand]`, AnyDice would somehow have to execute one block of code when `[sand]` is non-zero (i.e. true) and another when it is zero (i.e. false) — but, since it's a die, AnyDice cannot tell which it is.  Thus the error.

However, for simple cases (such as choosing the value of a variable based on a die roll) there's a work-around.  All you need is a helper function [like this](https://anydice.com/program/286e8/graph):

```
function: if CONDITION:n then A else B {
  if CONDITION { result: A } else { result: B }
}

FOO: [if d2 = 1 then 42d6 else 23 + 17d8]
```

Wait, so why does it work inside the helper function, then?!?

The answer is the little `:n` marker at the end of the parameter name `CONDITION` in the function definition.  That `:n` tells AnyDice to do whatever it needs to do in order to *convert that parameter into a number* before running the function, no matter what the actual value given in the function call is:

- If the given value is already a number, AnyDice just passes it to the function unchanged.
- If the given value is a sequence, AnyDice will sum it and pass the sum to the function.
- If the given value is a die, AnyDice will *call the function for every possible (summed) value of the die* and collect the results of all those function calls into a single custom die, weighted according to their probabilities!

So, basically, in the last case AnyDice *does* manage to create the "quantum superposition"* of all possible results of running the function for different rolls of the given die!

But it can only do that *for functions* because AnyDice functions are deliberately designed so that they cannot have externally visible side effects: no matter what happens inside the function, the *only* observable thing that comes *out* of the function is a single number (or die).  (For example, if you try to change the value of an external variable inside a function, it will revert back to its original value when the function ends.)  And AnyDice knows how to represent superpositions of different possible numbers as discrete probability distributions (a.k.a. "dice").

---

<sup>*) It's actually just a plain old non-quantum statistical superposition — no complex numbers are involved.  But the [general principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superposition_principle) is in fact the same.</sup>

---

Anyway, the main limitation of the helper function above is that it only works for choosing between two different *expressions* (like `42d6` and `23 + 17d8` in the example above).  An actual `if` statement can do more complex things, since it can choose between two completely different block of program code, which could even include things like different `output` statements.

For example, in your sample program you have the following code (which I've re-indented for clarity):

```
if [additionalcheck] < 0 {
  RL_TEMP: 0
} else {
  RL_TEMP: 0
  ROLL_RESULT: 1d12 + CHARACTERISTIC_BONUS
  if ROLL_RESULT > ROLL_LEVEL {
    RL_TEMP: 1
  }
}
```

Obviously, you can't just directly convert that into the `[if CONDITION then A else B]` form.  But we *can*, in fact, rearrange it so that it can be converted.  The trick is to move everything except the final assignment to `RL_TEMP` outside the `if` blocks, like this:

```
ROLL_RESULT: 1d12 + CHARACTERISTIC_BONUS
if [additionalcheck] < 0 {
  RL_TEMP: 0
} else {
  if ROLL_RESULT > ROLL_LEVEL {
    RL_TEMP: 1
  } else {
    RL_TEMP: 0
  }
}
```

and then convert that to something like this:

```
ROLL_RESULT: 1d12 + CHARACTERISTIC_BONUS
RL_TEMP: [if [additionalcheck] < 0 then 0 else [if ROLL_RESULT > ROLL_LEVEL then 1 else 0]]
```

In this particular case, we can in fact simplify that further.  First, we can combine the two nested conditions using the `&` operator:

```
ROLL_RESULT: 1d12 + CHARACTERISTIC_BONUS
RL_TEMP: [if [additionalcheck] >= 0 & ROLL_RESULT > ROLL_LEVEL then 1 else 0]
```

It also turns out that `[if CONDITION then 1 else 0]` is actually redundant, since AnyDice already represents "true" and "false" as the numbers 1 and 0.  So all we really need is:

```
ROLL_RESULT: 1d12 + CHARACTERISTIC_BONUS
RL_TEMP: [additionalcheck] >= 0 & ROLL_RESULT > ROLL_LEVEL
```

In general, if `CONDITION` could take values *other than* 0 and 1, we'd also need to force any non-zero values to 1.  In that case probably the simplest expression equivalent to `[if CONDITION then 1 else 0]` would be `CONDITION != 0`.  (Technically, if `CONDITION` could be a sequence, we'd actually need to use something like `CONDITION + 0 != 0` or `!!CONDITION`.)  But the AnyDice logical operators `&` and `|` are already guaranteed to always yield 0 or 1 (or dice with 0 and 1 as the only possible values) — as are comparison operators like `>` when applied to numbers — so we don't need to do that here.