# Probability help on rolling two D4 with all doubles counting as zero except double 4s, which count as 4

Tags: statistics, dice

So I have devised a game system involving two D4 being rolled to determine movement on a chart.  It works by tabulating the difference between the dice pips on each die, e.g., Die 1=rolls '1' vs Die 2=rolls '4' resulting in 4-1=3 movement.  The point is to allow for '0' movement when doubles are rolled.  But I also wanted to allow for a roll of '4' so I set a roll of double 4s to equal 4 movement, while all other doubles cancel, or zero movement.  I have tried calculating this myself but I would appreciate some help to check my work and offer any corrections or suggestions.  So....

1. Five possible outcomes on two D4:  0,1,2,3,4
2. The probabilities for each option are not equal: **4** is least likely at 1/16 (0.0625)
3. **0** requires (1|1), (2|2) or (3|3), so that is 3x more likely than 1/16 so 1/16 + 1/16 + 1/16 = **3/16** (0.1875) correct?  The rest I will do based on "differences" between the dice
4. Difference of **1**:  (1|2), (2|1), (2|3), (3|2), (3|4) and (4|3).  So would my probability for a "**1**" be **6/16** (0.375)?
5. Difference of **2**: (3|1), (4|2), (2|4) and (1|3).  So **2** is 4/16 (0.25)?
6. Difference of **3**: (4|1), (1|4).  So **3** is 2/16 (0.125)?
7. Summary from highest probability to lowest:  1 (38%), 2 (25%), 0 (19%), 3 (13%), 4 (6%)

Did I get that right?

If so, then my last question concerns the mean value for everything?  Definitely need some help here.  The zeros are screwing with my brain here. I presume the mean value should be greater than 1 but less than 2.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] if you haven't done so yet: you may find guidelines and useful suggestions about posting Q&A here. Happy gaming!

Answer (score 7):

#### The probabilities are right, but beware of approximations.

You got the right probabilities in terms of fractions, but when you approximated them with percentages you get a sum of 101%. You are adding 0.5% in items 4 and 6.

A further confirm can be obtained by simulating the rolls and computing the distances via your rules. The histogram below depicts the simulation of 1 million rolls (blue bars) and compares the empirical distribution with the theoretical one (orange dots). [image: Comparison between theory and simulation]

#### For the average movement you can use the formula for the expected value.

The formula for the [expected value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Random_variables_with_finitely_many_outcomes) \${\rm E}[X]\$ of a  discrete random variable \$X\$ that can take the values \$x_1, x_2,\dots,x_n\$  is given by
$$
{\rm E}[X] = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i P(x_i)
$$

where \$P(x_i)\$ is the probability of each value. This formula takes into account the fact that the values have different probabilities: this is a sort of weighted mean, where the weights are given by the probabilities. The higher the probability of a value is, the higher its contribution to the average is.

In this case you have
$$
{\rm E}[X] = 0 \frac{3}{16} + 1\frac{6}{16} + 2\frac{4}{16} +3\frac{2}{16} +4\frac{1}{16} = \frac{24}{16} = 1.5
$$

Your intuition that the average movement should be between 1 and 2 is correct.

Comment: Wow! Thank you for both the promt and informative reply!

Comment: @behemothbeer You're welcome! You can wait a little bit, and if you find the answer useful you may mark it as accepted, meaning that it solves your problem. Usually, it may be ok to wait at least a day before marking an answer as accepted, in order to allow people from different timezones to see your question and eventually contribute.

Comment: Got it.  Thanks.

Comment: Actually, I do have one further question. The "0" result could turn out to be a problem.  Probably not, but I can see how it might.  Making 0 and 3 equally likely would be the fix.  But not sure how I could do that without making 4 more likely (i.e., making 1|1 doubles equal to 4), or making other rules convoluted.

Answer (score 2):

[Eddymage's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/207970/36419) is correct, but I thought I would provide a supplementary answer to introduce one of RPG.SE's favorite tools: [AnyDice](https://anydice.com/). (We even have a tag for it: [anydice](/questions/tagged/anydice).)

After [wrestling with some error messages](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/192067/36419) for a while, I was able to implement your rolling strategy using two functions:

- `movehelper`: takes two numbers (i.e. the results of your rolls) and returns the difference between the higher and the lower, *unless* both numbers are 4, in which case it returns 4.
- `move`: feeds two `1d4`s into `movehelper` and returns the result. (This is technically unnecessary—you could call `output [movehelper 1d4 1d4]` directly— but I liked the idea of having a neat wrapper.)

The program is here: https://anydice.com/program/3162d

[image: A screenshot of the AnyDice program described and linked above, including its outputs]

As you can see, AnyDice shows you the probabilities of each result.

- **0**: 18.75% chance
- **1**: 37.5% chance
- **2**: 25% chance
- **3**: 12.5% chance
- **4**: 6.25% chance

The two numbers in parentheses after "output 1" are the mean/average result (1.5) and the standard deviation (1.12).

---

You mentioned in a comment that you might want **0** and **3** to be equally likely. Under your current scheme, **0** has a 3/16 chance of occurring, while **3** has a 2/16 chance.

The simplest way to implement this would be to say that a double-1 roll is not a valid result, i.e. roll again. This would change the chances of both **0**'s and **3**'s to 2/15.

AnyDice program for that strategy: https://anydice.com/program/31632

[image: A screenshot of an AnyDice program almost identical to the previous program, but modified to return no result when both dice are 1.]

This raises your mean result to 1.6.

Comment: Wow, thanks for doing that!  Definitely helpful.

Comment: I very much like the 1/1 null, so "roll again."  That would actually work rather neatly as a bookend to the 4/4 roll.  Thank you!